# Looking for a sensor that measures heart/pulse rate

Tags: sensors

I am looking for a sensor which is able to measure heart/pulse rate. Apart from the common pulse sensor [from here](https://pulsesensor.com/), are there any others?

I have seen people recommending [this](https://www.dfrobot.com/product-399.html) as well, and it seems more accurate. Should I get the piezo vibration sensor or are there better sensors? Hoping for something that is easy to use (Like the pulse sensor where you can just place your finger onto the sensor)

Cross-post from: https://www.reddit.com/r/arduino/comments/8f051k/looking_for_a_sensor_which_measures_heartpulse/ and https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=543857.0

Comment: `sensor which is able to measure heart/pulse rate` means that the sensor calculates the pulse rate and outputs the final value to the microcontroller ............. are you sure that is what you actually want?  .... or do you want a sensor that detects a heartbeat?

Comment: @jsotola yeah detects heartbeat. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 3):

The commonly used approach is to use an infrared source and sensor pressed against the skin.  Usually the finger tip is all that is needed. In addition to pulse, many have also incorporated an Oxygen measurement feature.

The 1st sensor you linked to appears to use this approach.  But instead of buying a ready made sensor, many have made a project of building their own...

This project has been done and published many times on the Internet.  There are well documented projects such as [this one from Rutgeurs](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/9a69/e809de07ca61e1aed19dc5c5c52d8ed93cdd.pdf).  As well as [this complex one from a journal called EDN](https://www.edn.com/design/medical/4434616/Simple-pulse-oximetry-for-wearable-monitor).  And [this one](https://hackaday.com/2010/05/02/diy-pulse-oximeter/) and [this one](http://www.makery.info/en/2014/11/11/bricole-it-yourself-capter-son-pouls-du-bout-du-doigt/) from various independent hackers.